# Advantages of pdo over mysql_* or mysqli_*

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have noticed that a lot of people are using or migrating to pdo, I have never used that before and I was really reluctant to change to that, I still have not changed anyway, but I would like to know from people who use the pdo everyday why I should change to that, I mean what advantages does it have over mysql_* or mysqli_*, I have googled a lot about  that but I have not found a satisfactory answer yet. Thanks

Comment: Driver support and named parameters.

Comment: I don't think I really understand that point, what driver or parameters?

Comment: Have you like looked at the manual or usage examples yet? Is there something specific you want to be rediscussed here? http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: PDO supports more databases not just MySQL and it let's you prepare your queries with named parameters and an associative array as opposed to using `?` everywhere like you'd do with `mysqli`.

Comment: For the record, this has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons

Comment: The answer is simple. PDO is usable with prepared tatements and mysqli is NOT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about supporting multiple databases with one app (although you can, with care). It's not about making it easy to change databases in the future (although it helps). It's about having *one consistent, sensible interface* to use regardless of database. Not only does that benefit programmers (by making their skills more broadly applicable) and projects (by making it easier for programmers to jump in), it also makes it a *lot* easier to create libraries that sit one layer above the data access layer. Perl has had the DBI for 20 years and it's been a decidedly good thing. PDO is a very similar concept (in fact it steals at least half of DBI's interface).

Answer (score 0):

PDO aims to support a transparent access to a various forms of SQL databases. It is a so called 'Data Access Abstraction Layer' for PHP.

If you restrict your application to use only SQL99 standard queries the above should be true in the *real life* ;).

Also PDO is an reliable interface for extension developers which are about to build a new database extension. They could just a write a driver dor PDO and the database can be accessed using a well known interface in PHP - the PDO interface.

Conclusion:

- PDO aims the similarize database access in PHP across various database types
- if using SQL99 standard queries, you can change the database product just be changing the connection string
- PDO is a well know interface for database access that can be used by extension developers

Comment: Correction, PDO is a data-access abstraction layer, not a database abstraction layer. For example, PDO cannot provide emulation for oracle native database functions against MySQL databases. http://us3.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

Answer (score -1):

PDO makes migrations easier between two different DBMSs. Some people also use it for application which support all DBMSs supported by PDO. But please note that this is usually a wrong practice: if you don't know very well a software, you shouldn't say to your users that you support it, because you would lie - because you couldn't solve real life problems.

mysqli is not an abstraction. It is a fast and reliable api for MySQL, and should be the first choice.