# [PHP][Mysql]cant output anything, from my If statement. anyone knows what went wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

can u tell me whats wrong?
i want to ouput "yes" if match is found and "No Result" result if there is no result.. it seems that it dont ouput anything..

```
    <?php
        $output = NULL;

        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $st = $_POST['search'];
            //Connect to the Database
            $mysqli =NEW mysqli("localhost","root","","exam");

            $search = $mysqli->real_escape_string($st);
            echo $st;

            //Query Database
            $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '$search'");
            if($result->num_rows > 0){
                echo "yes";
            }
        else{
            echo "No RESULT";
        }
    }

?>
<form>
    <input type="TEXT" name="search"/><br>
    <input type="SUBMIT" name="submit" value="search"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Add **ini_set('display_errors',1);** on the line after **<?php** .

Comment: @user2182349 believe it or not and strangely enough, that (error reporting) won't throw them anything. Forms fail silently when using POST arrays and no (post) form method.

Comment: If you are searching you might want to use `like` or full text searching rather than `=`. The `=` will require an exact match..

Comment: @Fred-ii- - excellent point.  Leaving my comment so others can learn from yours.

Comment: @user2182349 *Cheers* - Yeah, I learned that one the hard way "once" *lol*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form doesn't specify `method` which defaults to GET and you're using `$_POST` arrays.

Therefore, you need to specify a "post" method for it.

Also, look into using PDO instead of raw mysqli connections for [some very important benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204220/advantages-of-pdo-over-mysql-or-mysqli).

Comment: there it is.. thanks! you're right I have to specify my method!